# Why define a compact set through subsequences?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, definition, compactness

There is a definition of a compact set, which involves subsequences. Namely:

Set $A \subset R^d$ is called compact, if for every sequence ${x_n}$ with $x_n \in A$ there exists a subsequence with a limit belonging to A.

This definition is a bit counter-intuitive to me. I get for example, what compactness means in terms of "closed and bounded set". It's pretty clear that if a set is not unbounded (not an infinitely stretching ball) and every sequence of points is fully included inside that ball (including the limit of this sequence) then we call it compact. This way it becomes clear why an 'open' ball can't be compact, namely, since its limit might lie on a surface of the ball, which does not belong to the set itself.

But I can't get what the definition through subsequences is supposed to mean.

Comment: This definition actually encodes the boundedness very subtly. What it tells you is that your sequence can't trail off to infinity (i.e. in some sense the points are all "close" to each other) and closure follows from the existence of the limit within the set. This is a _terrible_ definition for compactness though as it does not generalize well to other contexts.

Comment: Worth noting that this is actually the definition of sequential compactness. For a metric space like $\mathbb R^n$, sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness, but this is not true for general topological spaces.

Comment: Any subsequence is a sequence on its own. Wasn't it sufficient to require that each sequence with its limit be in A? Why define through subsequences?

Comment: The original sequence might not be convergent. Consider $x_n = (-1)^n$ and $A = \{1\}$.

Comment: @Eval Not every sequence is convergent. And if you mean "every convergent sequence has a limit in $A$" then this is equivalent to "$A$ is closed". For example $A=\mathbb{R}^d$ itself satisfies it. No, this is not equivalent to compactness.

Comment: Also note that there is no such thing as "closed and bounded" definition. You are referring to Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem which characterizes compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ only.

Comment: The question isn't a bad one, but I'm not sure what kind of answer would be appropriate for it. For $\mathbb{R}^n$, a set is compact iff it's closed and bounded (in essence, because the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, and closed balls fill $\mathbb{R}^n$). That's not true in arbitrary spaces, even in metric spaces.

Comment: Just adding that the true definition of compactness is "every open cover of $U$ has a finite subcover". That means that if $U$ is inside any collection of open sets, then you can take only finitely many open sets of that collection to cover $U$. For complete metric spaces, this is equivalent to your definition. For $\mathbb{R}^n$, this is also equivalent to "closed and bounded".

Comment: @freakish Sometimes, particularly in introductory analysis courses, compactness in $\mathbb R$ is defined as being closed and bounded, and this is justified by Heine-Borel. You might question the motivation for this definition, but it is certainly a definition used in some circumstances.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are looking for here.  The definition means exactly what it says.  Maybe your question is why anyone bothers to make this definition, instead of just always using "closed and bounded"?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist that's interesting. I've never heard anyone defining compactness in such a way, but I guess this is possible.

Comment: That is exactly the case. I'm in Analysis course at a University in Germany.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly relate the subsequential notion of compactness to the standard open cover definition of compactness.  It might be useful to note first that compactness is, at root, a generalisation of finiteness.  Finite sets tend to be easy to prove things about because we can work by exhaustion: each element can be individually inspected, if necessary, to prove or disprove a hypothesis.  Compactness generalises that to infinite sets by giving us a way to reduce things to the finite case: if we can say something about an open set then compactness says we only need to inspect finitely many such open sets to obtain a result about whatever the set covers.

So: compactness is, by definition, the notion that every open cover of a set has a finite open subcover.  In some[1] topologies we can directly connect this to sequences: around each element of a sequence we can find/construct an open set.  If we take those sets large enough then we have an open cover of the space.  If there is a finite subcover, then the space is compact.  But a finite subcover is, by our construction, a subsequence of our original sequence.
This has to be true for every sequence in the space though: if we can find a sequence where we can't construct an open cover of the space using it, then the space cannot have an open cover.  Hence sequential compactness.

[1] Not all; hence why subsequential compactness is less useful as a definition.

Comment: You connected the dots, thank you!

Comment: I have a question re your final point: I thought that the content of the Eberlein-Šmulian theorem was that, for the weak topology on a Banach space (and this topology may not be metrisable), compactness, sequential compactness, and limit point compactness were all equivalent. Is this consistent with the point you make?

Comment: I understand the distinction between the weak-* and the weak topology. My understanding was that the weak-* topology is an example of a non-metrisable topology, hence the use of “e.g.”. However, if it is true that for the weak topology, sequential compactness and compactness are equivalent, how is it correct to say that any non-metrisable topology will not admit a notion of subsequential compactness?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist thank-you; I've gone back and rechecked the Eberlein-Smulyan theorem and I see your point.  I would delete the answer if I could, but it's accepted now.  Please downvote though.  I shall remove most of the footnote in the meantime.

Comment: Compactness under the usage of the AC has another meaning too. 
A space is compact if every Filter in that space has a closure point.